# how to fix the issue in AS..? ScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener

Tags: android, scrollview

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollMenu"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private void initViews() {
        scrollMenu = findViewById(R.id.scrollMenu);
        scrollMenu.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            }
        });
//        }
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dsmsoft.traccia.sampleui, PID: 12790
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dsmsoft.traccia.sampleui/com.dsmsoft.traccia.sampleui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at ndroid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.dsmsoft.traccia.sampleui.MainActivity.initViews(MainActivity.java:25)
        at com.dsmsoft.traccia.sampleui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Process 12790 terminated.

Comment: You forgot to add your code, and to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly, otherwise the question/code is unreadable and  cannot be properly answered.

Comment: Add your code and layout

Comment: scrollMenu = findViewById(R.id.scrollMenu);
        scrollMenu.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                System.out.println("--scrollX--" + scrollX + "--scrollY--" + scrollY + "--oldScrollX--" + oldScrollX + "--oldScrollY--" + oldScrollY);
            }
        });

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional code or XML. Please don't post it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your widget setOnScrollListener is null .Do you forget findViewById()?

Comment: first i initialize the id in scroll view, and again show this...!

Comment: @RahamathTullaA The error is telling that `scrollMenu` is null  at which you are trying to invoke event listener `setOnScrollChangeListener`. My suggestion is that you check the layout for the corresponding activity and there exists the `ScrollView` with `scrollMenu` id.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any other layout such as constraint layout and inside that a scroll view

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="109dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/screen_background_light" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="First Name :"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView14"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.217"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @ Rahamath Tulla A  if you found the solution with the help of my answer please accept the answer by turning the check button to green